# C - Compiling with -Wall doesn't warn about uninitialized variables

Tags: c, llvm-gcc

I have an example flawed program that should give exactly one warning about an uninitialized variable, but when I compile it gcc doesn't give me any warnings.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int foo;

    printf("I am a number: %d \n", foo);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is what I run: `cc -Wall testcase.c -o testcase`

And I get no feedback. As far as I know this should produce:

```
testcase.c: In function 'main': 
testcase.c:7: warning: 'foo' is used uninitialized in this function
```

It appears to warn Zed Shaw correctly in a [similar example](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/learn-c-the-hard-waych4.html#x9-270004.3) in his C tutorial). This is the example I had first tried and noticed that it wasn't working as expected.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

Version of gcc:

```
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.1.00)
```

Comment: Use Clang, be done with it `;-)`.

Comment: rubenvb, that turned out to be what worked, post that as an answer and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org), be done with it. Seems like a bug in GCC, cause Clang warns like it should.

Comment: More info: updating gcc was also an option, but using clang turned out to be by far the better choice for me.

Answer (score 8):

Are you compiling with optimisation turned on? Here's what my `man gcc` page says:

> ```
>   -Wuninitialized
>        Warn if an automatic variable is used without first being
>        initialized or if a variable may be clobbered by a "setjmp" call.
>
>       These warnings are possible only in optimizing compilation, because
>        they require data flow information that is computed only when
>        optimizing.  If you do not specify -O, you will not get these
>        warnings. Instead, GCC will issue a warning about -Wuninitialized
>        requiring -O.
> ```

My version of gcc is:

```
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.1.00)
```

Actually, I just tried this on a gcc 4.4.5 and I *do* get the warning without using `-O`. So it depends on your compiler version.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried `cc -Wall -O testcase.c -o testcase` and `cc -Wuninitialized -O testcase.c -o testcase` with no difference. Also gcc isn't issuing a warning about -Wuninitialized requiring -O.

Comment: @NickKnowlson: It appears that in gcc 4.2, `-Wall` does not imply `-Wuninitialized`. Also, that version of gcc appears unable to detect that `foo` is in fact unused.

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.2.1/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options The docs say otherwise, looks like. "that version of gcc appears unable to detect that foo is in fact unused" So is that the real answer then? This version can't detect foo is uninitialized for some reason? I'll try some more scenarios and see if I can create any conditions where it can.

Answer (score 2):

Update your compiler.

```
$ cat test.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int foo;
    printf("I am a number: %d \n", foo);
    return 0;
}
```

```
$ gcc -Wall -o test ./test.c
./test.c: In function ‘main’:
./test.c:7:11: warning: ‘foo’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++,go --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.6 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.6 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.6.1 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) 
$
```

Comment: I can confirm GCC 4.5.3, 4.6.3, and 4.7.0 all warn on this.

Comment: @rubenvb: You can (probably) only confirm that your distro has reasonably nice settings in default profile, pure vanilla gcc does not even turn optimizations on (-O, nor --march=native, --mtune=native, no graphite no nothing).
Mea culpa if you have compiled gcc by hand and can say otherwise.

Comment: His problem is prolly with using apples dist version of package, llvm is front-end is also obsolete (deprecated) afaik.

Comment: @AoeAoe as a matter of fact I did build GCC myself, and did not mess with the default profile (or with the `CFLAGS` environment variable, I'm on Windows `;-)`).

Answer (score 0):

A compiler is not required by the C Standard to warn when an uninitialized variable is accessed. A compiler is even not required to warn if a program invokes undefined behavior (assuming there is no syntax error and no constraint violations).

With `gcc` you can enable warnings for uninitialized variables with `-Wuninitialized`. As others noted, with recent versions of `gcc`, `-Wuninitialized` is enabled when `-Wall` is specified.

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but I am already familiar with all this. :)

Comment: Also, I was curious about this and it appears `-Wuninitialized` has been enabled when `-Wall` is specified at least since version 2.95.3 (March 16, 2001). So not too recent anymore! :) http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.3/gcc_2.html#SEC8